XLSX Exporting One2Many Fields creates blank space (Odoo)
Im using Odoo's default export xlsx action and there's an unlikely behavior where it creates a huge gap between the previous one2many field and to the current one2many field. The xlsx file looks like this when opened in Excel, Sheets, or Odoo's spreadsheet:

How can I fix that and make it look like this:

Thank you!
